# UFW not blocking connections to docker instance

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, ufw

I have a webservice running inside a docker instance which was run using the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4040:4040 ....
```

My UFW rules look like this:

```
~ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
4040                       DENY        Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
4040                       DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

When I access the box directly via its IP, I can access port 4040.  Why is the ufw rule not blocking it?

Note: As part of the docker installation, I changed

DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"
to
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"

in /etc/default/ufw as per dockers instructions here (http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/#docker-and-ufw)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and resolved it by using IPTABLES instead.

Example to only allow 3306 from source ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:

Adds an accept for source matching our ip to line 1 of the FORWARD chain

`iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -i eth0 -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

Drops all other connections on the FORWARD chain for that port

`iptables -I FORWARD 2 -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3306 -j DROP`

Using the line numbers (1 & 2) forces the rules to be added above the ones created by docker such as:

-A FORWARD -d 0.0.0.0/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Be ware: when restarting the container the newly created container will be prepended onto those IP table rules thus you have to re initialize those exact same iptable changes...

Answer (score 3):

There is a know issue related with this.
Basically, docker is configuring Iptables behind UFW.

More information:

- http://www.acervera.com/blog/2016/03/05/ufw_plus_docker
- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4737

The short possible response:

```
Set DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT" in /etc/default/ufw
Set DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false" in /etc/default/docker
```

Comment: and then restart docker and ufw

Answer (score 0):

Try running the container with a specific IP.

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:4040:4040 ...
```