# UFW rules don't work with docker

Tags: firewall, ufw, docker

I have a 12.04.4 server, and I have enabled ufw, and have tried to block port `8080`. However, it is still open.

```
$ sudo ufw deny 8080
Rule added
Rule added (v6)

$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 8080                       DENY IN     Anywhere
[ 4] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 5] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 6] 8080                       DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

Thoughts? I can still access the website that is on 8080. I have rebooted the system several times. The IP address is handled via static assignment, but I can't find anything that would indicate that that is the problem.

The service I'm trying to block is on a docker instance, however [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416907/ufw-not-blocking-connections-to-docker-instance) did not help.

Comment: Do you want both protocols or does it matter? And do you have gufw installed?

Comment: I also assume you haven't been tinkering with iptables.

Comment: @Seth the system is ipv4 only, so I don't care about v6. And, no, I haven't.

Comment: I meant tcp/udp.

Comment: I need tcp blocked, there is nothing on that udp port.

Comment: Try: `sudo ufw delete deny 8080` and then `sudo ufw deny proto tcp from any to port 8080`. `sudo ufw reload`. If that doesn't work it's either a weird bug/qwerk or maybe the order of your rules confuses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docker template that [I am using](https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker) is for Discourse. I solved it by editing the `containers/app.yml` file to include this under the ''expose' section:

```
 - "127.0.0.1:20080:80"
```

This means that it routes port 20080 on 127.0.0.1 to port 80 on the docker instance, thus removing the need entirely for a ufw rule.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it.

When I enter the command: `sudo ufw deny 80`, I could connect to myself, But other host could not.

I suggest you try to connect from any other than you.

Comment: Aha, I wondered if that could be it.

Comment: I'm ssh'ed into the server on the other side of the country, and I'm successfully accessing the system from my local web browser.

Answer (score 0):

The iptables docker rules are **evaluated** after the ufw ones. I wanted to restrict all IPs except one (of a VPN server) and I found the better solution in the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host)